# Rails/Devise - Customize flash message (devise.en.yml) with a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like to customize the following flash msg provided by devise
in the devise.en.yml file:

```
devise:
   failure:
      unconfirmed: 'You have to confirm your account before continuing.'
```

with ruby code in order to get a link to new_user_confirmation_path.

in other words, I want my flash message displays something like :

```
'You have to confirm your account before continuing. Didn't receive confirmation instructions?'
```

where 'Didn't receive confirmation instructions?' is a link to new_user_confirmation_path.

I would like to know if I can do this without editing the user controller cause Devise doesn't provide it by default.

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`new_user_confirmation_path` is a static url equivalent to `/users/confirmation/new`

So you can just do this in your devise.en.yml file:

```
devise:
  failure:
    unconfirmed: "You have to confirm your account before continuing. <a href='/users/confirmation/new'>Didn't receive confirmation instructions?</a>"
```

In the controller actions where you display your flash make sure you have `.html_safe` e.g. `flash[:error].html_safe`

Answer (score 3):

In one of my apps I am using Devise and CanCan.  I rescue from CanCan's errors with something like the following in my application conroller.

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  if current_user
    flash[:error] = exception.message
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:error] = t("devise.failure.unauthenticated")
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

Perhaps you could do something similar and rescue from Devise?  Your flash message could then be something like:

```
flash[:error] = t("devise.failure.unconfirmed") + link_to "Didn't receive confirmation instructions?", new_user_confirmation_path
```

Even better would be to put the "Didn't receive..." in it's own translation yml if need be.

Answer (score 3):

I think the right way for Rails 3 & Rails 4 to add required links and other information to Devise flash messages is to write your own `Devise::FailureApp`:

```
# lib/custom_failure.rb
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def i18n_options(options)
    path = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.new_user_confirmation_path
    link = ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to(I18n.t('.unconfirmed_link_text', options), path)

    super(options).merge(new_user_confirmation_link: link)
  end
end
```

And add interpolation to translations:

```
devise:
  failure:
    unconfirmed: You have to confirm your account before continuing.%{new_user_confirmation_link}
    unconfirmed_link_text: Didn't receive confirmation instructions?
```

don't forget to add to `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understand put question right the bit of code t('devise...you must place to our view, where you want to show this message.

For example `devise/new.erb`:

```
<%= t('devise.failure.unconfirmed',
      :confirm_link => link_to(
        t('devise.failure.confirm_link_text'),
        new_user_confirmation_path).html_safe
      ) unless user.confirmed %>
```

Comment: Hi potapuff, I'll rewrite the question in order to make it clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in your devise specific layout: `app/views/layouts/devise.html.slim`

```
- flash.each do |type, message| 
  - if ['alert', 'error', 'notice'].include?(type.to_s)
    .alert-box class=type
      => message
      - case message
      - when t('devise.failure.unauthenticated')
        = link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name)
      - when t('devise.failure.unconfirmed')
        = link_to "Didn't receive confirmation instructions?", new_confirmation_path(resource_name)
      - when t('devise.failure.locked')
        - if resource_class.unlock_strategy_enabled?(:email) 
          = link_to "Didn't receive unlock instructions?", new_unlock_path(resource_name)
```