# Is it possible to add link to the flash message when it's confirmed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Devise.
When the user succeeded at confirmation, the flash message appears.
I'd like to add a link to it.

So I want this message instead

`Your account was successfully confirmed. You are now signed in. Go to your profile page, and edit it!`

Then the part of `profile` should be the link to `example.com/users/username/edit`

How can I make it possible?

**devise.en.yml**

```
confirmations:
  confirmed: 'Your account was successfully confirmed. You are now signed in.'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008059/rails-devise-customize-flash-message-devise-en-yml-with-a-link-to?rq=1

Comment: By the way: When working without devise and you have controllers you can use the method [`view_context`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Context.html) to access any view method inside your models or controllers. E.g.: `view_context.link_to("link text", link_path)`

Comment: @Charles That's great to hear about that. Thanks:) Could you please put that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had trouble implementing these solutions. All I needed was a simple HTML link in the flash. Here's how I implemented it in Rails 4.1. I just had to sanitize my flash messages in app/views/shared/_flash.html.erb:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name %>">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215</a>
    <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
      <div id="flash_<%= name %>"> <%= sanitize(msg) %> </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And in my controller, I just entered HTML directly and without .html_safe. Works a treat!

```
flash[:notice] = %Q[Please <a href="#">click here</a>]
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the method [`view_context`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Context.html) to access any view method inside your models and controllers.

For example:

```
def index
  flash[:notice] = "Go to your #{view_context.link_to("profile page", link_path)}, and edit it!"
  redirect_to link_path
end
```

Update `link_path` accordingly.

Comment: When I used this method, I had to attach .html_safe at the end of the message string. Without that, the anchor tag and its contents showed as plain-text on the page.

Comment: Does not work with Rails 5.0. Even with `.html_safe`.

Comment: Yeah, that's interesting... I wonder what changed. When I call `html_safe` on the flash message *inside the template*, then it works. Such as `<%= notice.html_safe %>`. I wonder why, though.