# Adding link to devise flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have to add resend confirmation link to devise flash message.

```
unconfirmed: "You have to confirm your account before continuing."
```

Was following this link: [Rails/Devise - Customize flash message (devise.en.yml) with a link_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008059/rails-devise-customize-flash-message-devise-en-yml-with-a-link-to/5527443#5527443)

But the link is not added instead the text is displayed as it is

Comment: Are you sure you used flash[:error].html_safe?

Comment: Yes added flash[:alert].html_safe in sessions controller

Comment: My session/new.html.erb file is as:     <% unless flash.nil? %>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= flash.inspect %>
    <%= name.inspect %>
    <%= content_tag :div, :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => "alert alert-error" do %>
    <% if name == :alert %>
    <%= content_tag :i,"", :class => "ss-icon ss-delete" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>

Comment: While inspecting flash and name I got #<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x0000000b2b0448 @used=#<Set: {:alert}>, @closed=false, @flashes={:alert=>"You have to confirm your account before continuing."}, @now=nil> :alert

Comment: Will you please add this information to the question (you can use the edit link)?  All the information needed to figure out the answer should be in the question itself.

Comment: The issue is resolved now. Added .html _safe to <%= content_tag :div, msg.html_safe %>